# Separate module with different dependencies for header and body section in angularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using `angularJS` in my project. Every page of my project is contained two main sections (header.html(as master page) and body section) and I'm including header section in all pages.
I need `angularJS` in header section to load some informations. I've defined `app` variable in my header section and every other pages are using this application variable(module).

```
var app = angular.module('myModule',[])
```

My problem is, I need to use `app` variable in some pages with different dependencies (like `ui.bootstrap`).
Should I define all of dependencies in my header section? like following example:

```
var app = angular.module('myModule',['ui.bootstrap', ...])
```

Can I use separate modules in my header and body sections?

Can I add dependency to my module after its definition?

My page structure:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-app="HeaderApp" ng-controller="HeaderCtrl"> ... </div>
    <div ng-app="BodyApp" ng-controller="BodyCtrl"> ... </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And Javascript files:

(Header.js)

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('HeaderApp', []);
    app.controller('HeaderCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
        LoadUserName($scope, $http);
    });

    function LoadUserName($scope, $http) {
        ...
    }
})();
```

(Body.js)

```
(function() {

    angular.module('BodyApp', ['HeaderApp','ui.bootstrap']);
    var app = angular.module('BodyApp');

    app.controller("BodyCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
           ...
        };

    });

})();
```

Comment: If my question is not clear let me know about it to edit my question.

Answer (score 1):

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('bootstraplessModule', [...]);
    ...
)();
```

and

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('bootstrappedModule', [ 'bootstraplessModule', 'ui.bootstrap' ]);
    ...
)();
```

> Can I use separate modules in my header and body sections?

Yes. Though I'm not sure if it has much sense to define them in two different places.

> Can I add dependency to my module after its definition?

No. But you can provide an array variable to define the modules dynamically.

Comment: Thanks, Let me check your answer.

Comment: Did you mean I should define two modules? I Edited the question, now I have two modules.

Comment: Now there is no error, but my second controller('BodyCtrl') doesn't work. In other word just my first module works.

Comment: Yes. The thing is that there shouldn't be two `ng-app`s, only one at time. So with separate modules you need to do `ng-app="bootstraplessModule"` on pages without bootstrap and `ng-app="bootstrappedModule"` on pages with it.

Comment: But I'm loading username in my header section by angularJS and I've included this section in all pages. In this case what can I do?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, the example with ui-bootstrap doesn't explain it, please, post a real example. Are you doing this to save bandwidth by not loading some js files? Because if you aren't, it doesn't seem to be a good idea to split the application module.

Comment: No, I just have separated header and body in two files and I am including Header.html in other pages. I need to load user name in header section. I don't want to duplication the code of loading user name in all of my pages.

Comment: It shouldn't work like that, it is better to load single `app.js` file in <head>, and and there should be no 'all of my pages' because Angular is SPA-oriented, only one page should be loaded. If you have server-side app and can't rewrite it to SPA, jQuery would be a better candidate.